# setState() doesn't update my state properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

This component has an **array of objects** in its state with a property '*userFavorites*'.

```
userFavorites: [{id: 1, title: 'A'}, {id: 2, title: 'B'}]
```

When I call postFavorite() I need to add a new object to '*userFavorite*'.

I'm setting the state with the *prevState* and spread operator.

Regardless how many times I update the state by calling postFavorite() my *prevState* param is always the same. With *prevState* being always the same only the last object being added to the array persists there.

Can someone spot my issue?

```
class Albums extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            userLoggedId: null,
            renderFavorites: false,
            userFavorites: []
        }
        this.getDetails = this.getDetails.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const state = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('albumsStore'));
        if(state) {
            this.setState(() => ({ userLoggedId: state.userLoggedId, renderFavorites: state.renderFavorites, userFavorites: state.userFavorites }));
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(this.props !== prevProps) {
            this.setState(() => ({ userLoggedId: this.props.userLoggedId, renderFavorites: this.props.renderFavorites, userFavorites: this.props.userFavorites }));
        }
        window.localStorage.setItem('albumsStore', JSON.stringify(this.state));
    }


    setFavorite(event, favorite) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.postFavorite();
    }

    postFavorite = async() => {
        const post = await postFavorite(this.state.userLoggedId, this.props.id);
        if(post.status === 200) {
            this.setState( prevState => ({
                userFavorites: [...prevState.userFavorites,  {id: this.props.id}]
            }));
        } else {
            console.log("Something went wrong");
        }
    }

    isFavorite(id) {
        return this.state.userFavorites.find(favorite => favorite.id === id) ?  true : false;
    }

    render() { ... }
```

This is my log after calling 'postFavorite' twice in two different 'elements' that triggers this method:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you pass in user favorites as a prop as assign it to state in the constructor then reset it in componentDidMount.  I'd take a look at that and at least remove the resetting user favorites in cDM...  Hope this helps.

Comment: @MarcM. I'm not resetting 'userFavorites' in cDM. I'm setting the state to what I have saved in localStorage. I need to persist the state and I'm using localStorage.

Comment: You are calling `postFavorite` from  `postFavorite` ? Are you sure you didn't messed up there ?

Comment: @AsafAviv it's without the "this.", probably is an external function. I use an underscore at internal functions to differ from external imported functions.

Comment: did you try to comment the componentDidUpdate function? try this to see if the state updates correctly.

Comment: @AsafAviv, it's an external function from utils/api.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo, I did. The CDU updates my state with new props. I have even hardcoded the props in the constructor, removed the CDU, and the problem still persists.

Comment: can you reproduce this small part of your code at https://codesandbox.io/ ? If you can, share the link here.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo I will try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182440/discussion-between-joaozito-polo-and-rafael-guedes).

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo the only way I found to reproduce it is making it work properly. Got to compare those two versions and try to spot the error.

Answer (score 0):

In **componentDidUpdate** ,  condition may be is the issue. Usually if its required to update the state with newProps, **componentWillReceiveProps** helps a lot.

`if(this.props !== prevProps) {`

Please try with below component. Hopefully it helps.

```
class Albums extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        userLoggedId: null,
        renderFavorites: false,
        userFavorites: []
    }
    this.getDetails = this.getDetails.bind(this);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        this.setState(() => ({ userLoggedId: nextProps.userLoggedId, renderFavorites: nextProps.renderFavorites, userFavorites: nextProps.userFavorites }));
}
componentDidMount() {
    const state = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('albumsStore'));
    if(state) {
        this.setState(() => ({ userLoggedId: state.userLoggedId, renderFavorites: state.renderFavorites, userFavorites: state.userFavorites }));
    }
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    window.localStorage.setItem('albumsStore', JSON.stringify(this.state));
}


setFavorite(event, favorite) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.postFavorite();
}

postFavorite = async() => {
    const post = await postFavorite(this.state.userLoggedId, this.props.id);
    if(post.status === 200) {
        this.setState( prevState => ({
            userFavorites: [...prevState.userFavorites,  {id: this.props.id}]
        }));
    } else {
        console.log("Something went wrong");
    }
}

isFavorite(id) {
    return this.state.userFavorites.find(favorite => favorite.id === id) ?  true : false;
}

render() { ... }
```

Comment: The problem persists. Your suggestion with componentWillReceiveProps is doing the same that I've done with componentDidUpdate. And componentWillReceiveProps is considered '_unsafe' by React, atm.